# Hosting PHP on WildFly 26?

Tags: java, php, wildfly, undertow

Is it still possible to host PHP-based sites on WildFly 26 (or undertow)? There's some documentation on the Web around doing this with (much) older version of JBoss. Has support been dropped?

I need Java EE for my webapp, but designers will often supply PHP for the static 'brochure' pages that front the site. It'd be great to host all these under the same server?

Comment: Are you referring to [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/)?

Comment: Are these pages *really* PHP or are they static HTML pages with a .php extension?    The product that @fvu shows hasn't been updated in about 8 years and it's PHP 5.  It's unclear that it would still work.  I wasn't aware that even that existed.

Comment: It'll most likely just be PHP for the HTML templating bits, contact us form etc.

Comment: I would think it would be better to convert these to static HTML rather than try to glue PHP onto Wildfly.